# Android Error Program type already present

Tags: java, android

I am struggling with an error since two day. Hope someone can help me.
I am using AndroidStudio 3.3.1 on MacOS. When I build the project, i receiver the following error message:

```
Error: Program type already present: com.loopj.android.http.BaseJsonHttpResponseHandler
```

My **build.gradle** looks like:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "lalalalalalala"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 7
        versionName "1.6"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.1.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    implementation 'com.github.delight-im:Android-AdvancedWebView:v3.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

as dependencies I have

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
}
```

in gradle.properties is

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m

android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

and in in gradle-wrapper.properties I have

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip
```

I start to believe is a bug of AndroidStudio 3.3.1.
Does anyone see a problem in my code ?
Any help is highly appreciated :)

edit:

```
package lalalalalala;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import com.loopj.android.http.*;

import im.delight.android.webview.AdvancedWebView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AdvancedWebView.Listener {

    private AdvancedWebView WebView;
    protected static boolean isActivityRunning;

    public static boolean checkIfAppIsRunnung()
    {
        return isActivityRunning;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Cookies
        AsyncHttpClient myClient = new AsyncHttpClient();
        PersistentCookieStore myCookieStore = new PersistentCookieStore(this);
        myClient.setCookieStore(myCookieStore);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView = (AdvancedWebView) findViewById(R.id.webWiew);
        WebView.setListener(this, this);
        WebView.setThirdPartyCookiesEnabled(false);

        Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, MyFirebaseMessagingService.class);
        startService(mIntent);


        WebView.loadUrl("lalalalalalala");
        WebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        WebView.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        // ...
    }



    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(String url, Bitmap favicon) { }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(String url) { }


    @Override
    public void onDownloadRequested(String url, String suggestedFilename, String mimeType, long contentLength, String contentDisposition, String userAgent) { }

    @Override
    public void onExternalPageRequest(String url) { }

}
```

Comment: Please post your main class or activity. This is usually an error when you've imported something that already exists. For example importing a class named Button when android.widget.button already exists.

Comment: Thanks for our help. I edited with the MainActivity class :) Please, I am desperate .....

Comment: where do you use the com.loopj.android.http.BaseJsonHttpResponseHandler class?

Comment: for exemple here "AsyncHttpClient myClient = new AsyncHttpClient();"

Comment: Do you have other classes/activities? It seems to be with BaseJsonHttpResponseHandler, if you've used that somewhere?

Comment: no, used only there

Comment: But you haven't used that class there. That name isn't used in that activity at all?